# Nested react component (Header) causing site to be unresponsive

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm trying to imbed my Header component into other components but every time I do, it causes the site to be unresponsive.

A couple of things I have tried include updated the components so the page will be, including the Header, enclosed in a fragment tag. I've also tried putting the Header inside a div to see if that will stop the behavior.

Here is the Header.js

```
export default class Header extends React.Component { 

    render() {
        return (
          <>  
            <header className="header__container">
                <img className="header__logo" src={logo} alt="company Logo" width='200' />
                <div className="header__title-container">
                  <h1 className="header__title">Angel Mortgage</h1>
                </div>
                <Nav />
            </header>
          </>  
        )
    }
```

And the Tools.js

```
export default class Tools extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            {/* <Header /> */}
            <NavLink className="nav__link" activeClassName="active" to='/MortgageRateEst'>Mortgage Rate Estimater</NavLink>
            <Route path='/MortgageRateEst' component={InputForm} />

            <Footer />
            </>
        );
    }
```

The  component does not display the same behavior even though it has a render as well. I presently have the  commented out so you can see where I want to put it.

I've used the same structure in previous projects but I'm at a loss on the cause of this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

#### Update

Further troubleshooting - I replaced the call to the Header with the actual code, and experienced the same behavior (as expected) - page unresponsive and no error logged on the console. I then removed the call to the linked Nav component and the page rendered. So the experience is the same - page unresponsive and no error logged; it's just one level deeper.

The Nav code

````
    render() {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="nav__container">
                <NavLink className="nav__link" activeClassName="active" to='/Contact Us'>Contact Us</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="nav__link" activeClassName="active" to='/Mascot'>Mascot</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="nav__link" activeClassName="active" to='/Tools'>Tools</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="nav__link" activeClassName="active" to='/InputForm'>Mortgage Rate Estimate</NavLink>
                <NavLink className="nav__link" activeClassName="active" to='/Payment Calculator'>Payment Calculator</NavLink>
                <Route path='/InputForm' component={InputForm} />
                <Route path='/Payment Calculator' component={PaymentAmort} />
                <Route path='/Contact Us' component={ContactForm} />
                <Route path='/Mascot' component={Mascot} />
                <Route path='/Tools' component={Tools} />
            </div>
          </>
        )
    }
}```
````

Comment: Are you seeing an error in the console? If so, what is it?

Comment: There is no error message in the console. The page is not rendering at all.

Comment: Without seeing your full project or having any more info, I'd *guess* that you're not importing something. Either Header.js doesn't import Nav, or Nav doesn't import something that it refers to, etc... But if that were the case, you should see plenty of error messages in your browser's dev console (or perhaps in your terminal if it was caught during the build).
Are you using create-react-app? 
It might help if you can share more of your code, or set something up on codesandbox

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using create-react-app, and I took the troubleshooting even deeper by replacing the call to Nav with the actual code as well. I've narrowed the issue even further. Of the five calls in Nav, three of them render properly and the others fail to load when they are included in the Nav calls. I'm going to continue troubleshooting those two components and will update on my findings.

Answer (score 0):

As of [React v16.2](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html) `React.Fragment` allows components to return multiple children. Doing `<>` is the same as `<React.Fragment>`.

Try explicitly typing `<React.Fragment>` because some build tools have trouble with `<>`.

```
export default class Tools extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {/* <Header /> */}
                <NavLink className="nav__link" activeClassName="active" to='/MortgageRateEst'>Mortgage Rate Estimater</NavLink>
                <Route path='/MortgageRateEst' component={InputForm} />

                <Footer />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No change in the behavior - page goes unresponsive and doesn't render at all.